# C++ Calculator Prog. Issue

Tags: c++

If anyone has some suggestions - I could utilize the help.  The program compiles, but does not
compute properly.  I have tried numerous reitterations and I am at an impase.  Any suggestions?
I have to initialize all these variables?  Thank you....

```
//This program mimics a calculator
//*****************************************

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
double firstint, secint, ansrlt, ansrlt2, ansrlt3, ansrlt4;
char operat;

cout << fixed << showpoint;
cout << setprecision(4);

cout << "This program mimics a standard calculator and outputs a result accurate to 4 decimal   
places." <<endl;
cout << '\n';

cout << "Please enter 1st Integer to be calculated: ";
cin >> firstint;
cout << '\n';

cout << "Please enter operation to be performed in the form of *, /, +, - : ";
cin >> operat;
cout << '\n';

cout << "Please enter 2nd Integer to be calculated: ";
cin >> secint;
cout << '\n';

if (operat == '/' && secint == 0)
    cout << "Division by 0 not allowed enter again." << endl;

cin.get();

if (operat == '*')
    ansrlt = firstint * secint;
    cout << firstint << " " << operat << " " << secint << " = " << ansrlt << endl;

cin.get();

if (operat == '/')
    ansrlt2 = firstint / secint;
    cout << firstint << " " << operat << " " << secint << " = " << ansrlt2 << endl;

cin.get();

if (operat == '+')
    ansrlt3 = firstint + secint;
    cout << firstint << " " << operat << " " << secint << " = " << ansrlt3 << endl;

cin.get();

    ansrlt4 = firstint - secint;
    cout << firstint << " " << operat << " " << secint << " = " << ansrlt4 << endl;

cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Homework eh? Killer. In what way does it not compute properly?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not an online debugger...

Comment: I did debug and compile, nothing was/is picked up.  the answer just outputs the same each time.  So for example 2+2 = 4; 2*2 = 4; 2-2 = 4; 2/2 = 4.  I will make the alterations now.  Also the { } are not in the text format either.  I constructed it per the text.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions as I am learning - working fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should explain what you do, what happens, and what you expected to happen - as that will generally make things a lot easier for 
anyone reading your question.

However, you're missing {} around the body of your if's everywhere.

e.g. it should be

```
if (operat == '*') { 
    ansrlt = firstint * secint;
    cout << firstint << " " << operat << " " << secint << " = " << ansrlt << endl;
}
```

(And get rid of the `cin.get()` calls, unless you're using them for debugging purposes)

Comment: note that use of an actual debugger would have revealed this in less time than it took to type the question. Learn how to use your tools and you'll be a happier developer.